# trying to write liquibase migration changelog for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, liquibase

how to write liquibase migration script for mongodb, which has an array of creditCards and I want to put something like "status" as "inactive" for an employee whose creditCard missing field "status". below is the collections

```html
{
   "empId":1,
   "availablePaymentModes":{
      "passportNumber":"XYZ",
      "creditCards":[
         {
            "bankName":"AA1",
            "cardNumber":"1234",
            "status": "active"
         },
         {
            "bankName":"AA2",
            "cardNumber":"1234"
         },
         {
            "bankName":"AA4",
            "cardNumber":"1234",
            "status": "active"
         }
      ]
   }
}
{
   "empId":2,
   "availablePaymentModes":{
      "passportNumber":"XY1",
      "creditCards":[
         {
            "bankName":"AA1",
            "cardNumber":"2234",
            "status": "active"
         },
         {
            "bankName":"AA2",
            "cardNumber":"2234"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check out the documentation on how to write [changelogs](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog.html) with [changesets](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changeset.html) for liquibase.  This is how a migration script gets written in Liquibase.

If it is easier, you can write you changelog in [sql](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/sql-format.html).

I would also recommend you take the [liquibase fundamentals](https://learn.liquibase.com/catalog/info/id:125,cms_featured_course:1) class b/c this question is easily answerable after spending a few hours to complete this course and you walk away with a certification.

So as long as you can take your collection from above and define it in sql, you should be able to put that in a changelog.sql, and point the url value in the liquibase.properties file to that changelog.sql and then run a liquibase update.

Comment: This answer is not helpful. Moreover, all posted links could simply be put in comments instead of an answer.